# What are the pros and cons for serving SPA content from a container?

Tags: docker, containers, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application, azure-aks

We are using pure SPAs for our apps and we have a choice of serving them as static content from azure web blob or from nginx containers in AKS. What are the pros and cons with each method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single-page-app does not require dynamic content serving, my recommendation is to don't waste compute power for static content at all.

Generally the complexity, configuration, overhead and not to mention the cost of dynamic serving defeats the purpose and storage services can be just perfectly abstracted with custom domains too.

I would only use nginx if you need some dynamic routing to proxy pass content, process, evaluate or alter headers and cookies, etc.